# i am getting a limit of 1 comment while finding the comment using post_id in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am able to retrieve just one comment while there are multiple comments for a post using `Comment.find_by_post_id(2)` command in rails. I am a newbie to rails and currently following a course on coursera.org. I am using ubuntu14.10

Comment: find_by will find only one element matching conditions. use Commen.where(post_id: 2)

Answer (score 0):

You Can find all comments of post using following.

```
Comment.where(post_id: 2)
```

This will return collection of result.

Please take a look at this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Provided your post class is registered to have many comments :

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end
```

you can go for :

```
Post.find(2).comments
```